# How to fix IOAF code GPU errors while using ARKit2 & Vision (VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest) on iPhone XS

Tags: ios, swift, computer-vision, arkit, apple-vision

While running ARKit on iPhone XS (with iOS 12.1.2 and Xcode 10.1), I'm getting errors and crashes/hangs while running Vision code to detect face bounds.

Errors I'm getting are:

```
2019-01-04 03:03:03.155867-0800 ARKit Vision Demo[12969:3307770] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Timeout Error (IOAF code 2)
2019-01-04 03:03:03.155786-0800 ARKit Vision Demo[12969:3307850] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Discarded (victim of GPU error/recovery) (IOAF code 5)
[SceneKit] Error: display link thread seems stuck
```

This happens on iPhone XS while running the following proof of concept code to reproduce the error (always happens within a few seconds of running the app) - https://github.com/xta/ARKit-Vision-Demo

The relevant ViewController.swift contains the problematic methods:

```
func classifyCurrentImage() {
    guard let buffer = currentBuffer else { return }

    let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer)
    let options: [VNImageOption: Any] = [:]
    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image, orientation: self.imageOrientation, options: options)

    do {
        try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.requests)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func handleFaces(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation] else { return }
        // TODO - something here with results
        print(results)

        self.currentBuffer = nil
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to use Apple's ARKit + Vision with `VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest`? Getting mysterious IOAF code errors is not correct.

Ideally, I'd also like to use VNTrackObjectRequest & VNSequenceRequestHandler to track requests.

There is decent online documentation for using VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest with Vision (and without ARKit). Apple has a page here (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/using_vision_in_real_time_with_arkit) which I've followed, but I'm still getting the errors/crashes.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who goes through the pain I just did trying to fix this exact error for `VNDetectRectanglesRequest`, here was my solution:

It seems that using a CIImage:

```
let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image, orientation: self.imageOrientation, options: options)
```

caused Metal to retain a large amount Internal Functions in my memory graph.

I noticed that Apple's example projects all use this instead:

```
let handler: VNImageRequestHandler! = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer,
                                                                    orientation: orientation,
                                                                    options: requestHandlerOptions)
```

Switching to use `cvPixelBuffer` instead of a `CIImage` fixed all of my random GPU timeout errors!

I used these functions to get the `orientation` (I'm using the back camera. I think you may have to mirror for the front camera depending on what you're trying to do):

```
func exifOrientationForDeviceOrientation(_ deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation) -> CGImagePropertyOrientation {

    switch deviceOrientation {
    case .portraitUpsideDown:
        return .right

    case .landscapeLeft:
        return .down

    case .landscapeRight:
        return .up

    default:
        return .left
    }
}

func exifOrientationForCurrentDeviceOrientation() -> CGImagePropertyOrientation {
    return exifOrientationForDeviceOrientation(UIDevice.current.orientation)
}
```

and the following as the `options`:

```
var requestHandlerOptions: [VNImageOption: AnyObject] = [:]
let cameraIntrinsicData = CMGetAttachment(pixelBuffer, key: kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, attachmentModeOut: nil)
if cameraIntrinsicData != nil {
            requestHandlerOptions[VNImageOption.cameraIntrinsics] = cameraIntrinsicData
}
```

Hopefully this saves someone the week that I lost!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `perform` method async, just as it is done in the link you've shared.
Try below code:

```
func classifyCurrentImage() {
    guard let buffer = currentBuffer else { return }

    let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer)
    let options: [VNImageOption: Any] = [:]
    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image, orientation: self.imageOrientation, options: options)

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        do {
            try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.requests)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code (previously I have tried using a serialQueue as per Apple's code), but the app does not work. Using your code above, I'm still getting errors/hangs:



`ARKit Vision Demo[13245:3429200] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Discarded (victim of GPU error/recovery) (IOAF code 5)
ARKit Vision Demo[13245:3429144] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Timeout Error (IOAF code 2)`

Comment: @xta That's strange, I ran the sample project and had no issues on an iPhone 7 device.

Comment: I agree since I can run the code on iPhone 7 fine, but will get the errors immediately with iPhone XS. Very frustrating since 7 = OK, XS = errors galore.

Answer (score 0):

Update: from what I can tell, the issue was retain cycles (or the lack of `[weak self]`) in my demo repo. In Apple's [sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/using_vision_in_real_time_with_arkit), they properly use `[weak self]` to avoid retain cycles and ARKit + Vision app runs on the iPhone XS.

Comment: how did you modify the code above to properly use `[weak self]`

Comment: I didn't modify the code above, I started over using the Apple project as a baseline https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/using_vision_in_real_time_with_arkit